# Intersec two sorted lists

Tags: r, intersection, feature-selection

I have a dataset with my actual data:

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(A = rnorm(15), 
                B = rnorm(15), 
                C = rnorm (15), 
                D = rnorm(15))
```

And another dataset with two outcomes:

```
annotation <- data.frame(Y = sample(1:3, 15, replace = TRUE), 
                         Z = sample(1:3, 15, replace = TRUE))
```

I created a function that returns a list of p-values:

```
ANOVAFeatureSelection <- function(data, labeles){
  # feature selection using ANOVA
  summaryModelAnova <- summary(aov(formula = as.matrix(data) ~ labeles))

  pValVec <- vector()
  i <- 1
  while(i <= length(summaryModelAnova)){
    pValVec[i] <- summaryModelAnova[[i]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]
    i <- i+1
  }
  return(pValVec)
}
```

Now I have two sorted lists of p-value for each variable `Y` and `Z`:

```
aovPval <- ANOVAFeatureSelection(df, annotation$Y)
pValueVectorY <- p.adjust(aovPval, method = 'fdr')
name(pValueVectorY) <- colnames(df)
pValueVectorY <- sort(pValueVectorY, decreasing = TRUE)

aovPval <- ANOVAFeatureSelection(df, annotation$Z)
pValueVectorZ <- p.adjust(aovPval, method = 'fdr')
name(pValueVectorZ) <- colnames(df)
pValueVectorZ <- sort(pValueVectorZ, decreasing = TRUE)
```

Is there a way to intersect the two sorted list obtaining a sorted list based on the p-values of bth lists? At the moment my code is:

```
intersection <- intersect.Vector(pValueVectorY,
                                 pValueVectorZ)
```

Comment: your code gives an error at this line `name(pValueVectorY) <- rownames(df)`. What is `intersect.Vector` ? What would be your expected output?

Comment: I edited the question. Intersect.Vector allows to do inner intersection of two lists, therefore the output is the elements that are in both lists

Comment: are you looking for `sort(c(pValueVectorY, pValueVectorZ), decreasing = TRUE)`